# How to copy columns from one worksheet to another on excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy certain column from one worksheet to another but when I apply my code, I get no errors but also no results. I get blank paper. I applied this methodolgy on copying a certain row and it was copied to another worksheet perfectly.

This is regarding the successful attempt to copy row.
The code works just fine:

```
Sub skdks()

Dim OSheet As Variant
Dim NSheet As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim LRow As Integer
Dim NSLRow As Integer

OSheet = "Tabelle3" 'Old Sheet Name
NSheet = "Tabelle5" 'New Sheet Name

LRow = Sheets(OSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'Last Row in Old Sheet

Sheets(OSheet).Activate

For i = 2 To LRow
'Finds last row in the New Sheet
    If Sheets(NSheet).Cells(2, 1) = "" Then
        NSLRow = 1
    Else
        NSLRow = Sheets(NSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    End If

'If cell has "certain # then..."
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(13, 2).Value Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets(NSheet).Cells(NSLRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This little piece of code is the failed attempt to copy column to another worksheet.

```
Sub trial()

Dim OSheet As Variant
Dim NSheet As Variant
Dim j As Integer
Dim LColumn As Integer
Dim NSLColumn As Integer

OSheet = "Tabelle2" 'Old Sheet Name
NSheet = "Tabelle5" 'New Sheet Name

LColumn = Sheets(OSheet).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  'Last Column in Old Sheet

Sheets(OSheet).Activate

For j = 2 To LColumn
'Finds last column in the New Sheet
    If Sheets(NSheet).Cells(1, 2) = "" Then
        NSLColumn = 1
    Else
        NSLColumn = Sheets(NSheet).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End If

'If cell has "certain # then..."
    If Cells(2, j) = Cells(13, 2) Then
        Cells(2, j).EntireColumn.Copy
        Sheets(NSheet).Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: What went wrong with your code? Any errors? • Note that `Sheets(NSheet).Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial` will paste always into the exact same cell `B2` each iteration of the loop `For j = 2 To LColumn`, so you paste over and over into the same cell overwriting what you pasted before.

Comment: Thing is that nothing is copied. Tabelle5 is totally blank. Wehn I try the code but with the row. I get correct copied cells. I ddnt get any errors. just blank worksheet.

Comment: Go through your code step-by-step using F8. See which steps are running and check the variable values, to figure out what exactly is going wrong. • Note that you should not use `As Integer` use `As Long` instead. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Also your sheet names should be `OSheet As String`. Never use `Variant` if there is a better possibility. `Variant` is always the worst choice.

Comment: I am a beginner with vba. This is my 2nd day working on it. I have minimum knowledge of it but I am trying to learn. I updated `OSheet as String` but still blank. No results.

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere (actually it's not bad for 2ⁿᵈ day). You just need to learn how to debug your code: Go through your code step-by-step using F8. [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)

Comment: I get no error. Sorry maybe I am not sure what to expect from the debugging. I will look into it. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Errors are easy to find because the show up. If there is no error you need to check the values of your variables in each step (that is what you do in debugging). So check the values of the variables and see if they are what you expected. You will also see which `If` statemenst are true and so on. So you see which way your code takes. Try to figure out wher it goes wrong or where variables show another value than expected.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I learned more about how to debug my code. I got to say, such a powerful tool. I worked with Fortran to solve numericla rpoblems and it lacks this.

Answer (score 0):

```
....
'If cell has "certain # then..."
If Cells(2, j) = Cells(13, 2) Then

    debug.Print Cells(2, j).Address; " = "; Cells(13, 2).Address; " ---- COPY"
    debug.print Cells(2, j).EntireColumn.address; Cells(2, j).EntireColumn.cells.count
    debug.Print Sheets(NSheet).Cells(2, 2).Address

    Cells(2, j).EntireColumn.Copy
    Sheets(NSheet).Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
....
```

[image]

With the line `If Cells(2, j) = Cells(13, 2) Then` you compare the different cells from row 2 (B2, C2, D2, ...) with the value of cell "B13". If the value is the same you copy this column to the new worksheet.

Is there any equal value in your data? If yes you should get an error message with your code.

You try to copy the values of an entire column to the range starting with "B2". Of cause there is not enough space for this.

=> Either you reduce the source range or you start the destination range on row 1!

Comment: Thank you. I guess the problem was that. Anyway I solve the problem in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the paste destination size, if you really want to paste the entire column, you either need to start at the beginning of the column or choose the entire column.  Also, I think you want to make the paste column increase with your `NSLColumn`

```
If Cells(2, j) = Cells(13, 2) Then
    Cells(2, j).EntireColumn.Copy
    Sheets(NSheet).Columns(NSLColumn + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess the problem was that. Anyway I solve the problem in a different way.